# T-SQL Recursive Query to Rebuild Historical Totals

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Looking for a way to generate "snapshots" of historical data when I have the final data, and the change to the data each week.

I have this data in table CurrentData:

```
CurrentDate   CurrentAmount
--------------------------
2013-07-24        400
```

And I also have this data in table ChangeData:

```
ChangeDate    ChangeAmount
--------------------------
2013-07-23        -2
2013-07-22        -4
2013-07-21        10
2013-07-20         1
```

And I want to be able to show what the data looked like over time.  For example:

```
TotalDate     TotalAsOfThisDate
--------------------------------
2013-07-24        400
2013-07-23        402
2013-07-22        406
2013-07-21        396
2013-07-20        395
```

Understanding I will have to build the total based off of the prior day's data each day, I have tried a plethora of different things, cursors, temp tables, etc.  Wondering how I would go about building this type of view in SQL.  I am running SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best performing query, but should work fine for small tables:

```
SELECT CurrentDate as TotalDate, CurrentAmount as TotalAsOfThisDate
FROM CurrentData
UNION ALL
SELECT ChangeDate, (SELECT CurrentAmount from CurrentData)  
                  -(SELECT SUM(ChangeAmount) 
                    FROM ChangeData cd2 
                    WHERE cd2.ChangeDate >= cd1.ChangeDate)
FROM ChangeData cd1
ORDER BY TotalDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you can pull with the OVER clause and a CTE....

```
  ;WITH Source AS (
        SELECT  CurrentDate , CurrentValue FROM CurrentData
        UNION   
        SELECT  ChangeDate , -ChangeAmount FROM ChangeData  )

SELECT CurrentDate,  SUM(CurrentValue)   
OVER (ORDER BY CurrentDate DESC)
FROM Source
```